# MySQL:select data in three table

Tags: mysql

I have three table in mysql:

```
1.t_item
    itemID    item_name     
      1        pen      
      2        luxury pen       


2.s_item
      itemID    item_name     
      1          shoes
      2          clothes
      3          computer


3.track
      trackID    item_no   item_type  
      1           1         t_item
      2           2         t_item
      3           2         s_item
```

And I want to get trackID, item name for item_no in table track.
How can I write the sql statement?In track,trackID 2,3 have same item_no but different item type, Can I use join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

```
(SELECT track.trackID, t_item.item_name FROM track
    LEFT JOIN t_item ON track.item_no=t_item.itemID 
    WHERE track.item_type = 't_item') 
UNION
(SELECT track.trackID, s_item.item_name FROM track
    LEFT JOIN s_item ON track.item_no=s_item.itemID 
    WHERE track.item_type = 's_item')
```

Comment: You can also get it in a single statement without using `Union`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, It will work:

```
(SELECT t.trackID,ti.item_name 
    FROM track t 
    LEFT JOIN t_item ti 
    ON t.item_no=ti.itemID AND t.item_type='t_item') 
UNION
(SELECT t.trackID,si.item_name 
    FROM track t 
    LEFT JOIN s_item si 
    ON t.item_no=si.itemID AND t.item_type='s_item')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT t.trackID, t.item_no, 
  (CASE WHEN t.item_type = 't_item' THEN ti.item_name
       WHEN t.item_type = 's_item' THEN si.item_name
  END) AS item_name
FROM track t
  LEFT JOIN t_item ti ON t.item_no = ti.itemID AND t.item_type = 't_item'
  LEFT JOIN s_item si ON t.item_no = si.itemID AND t.item_type = 's_item';
```

Here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24f22/9).